# Finding a value on a HTML page with JSoup via data-bind

Tags: java, html, jsoup

making simple Bitcoin price tracking program for fun. I have this so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=USDT-BTC";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String price = document.select("#").text();
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
    }
```

I need to set price to the value inside this HTML tag

```
<span data-bind="text: summary.displayLast()">4183.96889999</span>
```

Seriously confused here, I think I'm missing something fundamental but can't figure out what, any help much appreciated <3

Comment: The price is being updated with some JS code and JSOUP cannot parse it. Google for "headless browser", like phantomJS, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the page written by JavaScript. Jsoup does not execute the JS code, so you see a blank text() in tag.
I think you have to send request to API by URL https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries and parse response in JSON format.